# HtmlHelper Generate Validation Markup in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, razorgenerator, html-generation

This is somehow related to [The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620322/create-get-defaulthtmlgenerator-from-mvc-controller/34621813#34621813)

I am using jquery unobtrusive validation. I have the following model

```
public  class MyModel
{

   [Required]
   public int ID { get; set; }


   [MinLength(2)]
   public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

I want to generate an html markup with validation(**This is what I want to generate my self using code**)

```
<input class="FormElement form-control valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID">

<input class="FormElement form-control valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-minlength="The field Description must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '2'." data-val-minlength-min="2" id="Description" name="Description" value="description changed 6">
```

My question is how Can I manually generate the markup from the model attributes inside my controller.

So My code will simply look like this

```
    private readonly IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator;
    private readonly IHtmlHelper helper;
    public MyController(IHtmlGenerator htmlGenerator, IHtmlHelper hh)
    {
        if (htmlGenerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlGenerator");

        this.htmlGenerator = htmlGenerator;
        this.helper = hh;
    }
   public IActionResult GenerateHtml()
    {

     HtmlHelper tempHelper= this.HtmlHelper;
      // Generate the markup for ID and Description here from model MyModel(With VALIDATION) 
    }
```

Comment: I really have hard time understanding what's being asked here and what particular problem we are trying to solve.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  I have Edited my question.